# Work around to unsolved npm link symlink requires?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, npm, npm-link

When developing an NPM package, it's common to use:

```
npm link
```

It allows to modify `<myPackage>` under development without the need of publishing and unpublishing all the time! The developer can make any changes locally and see it immediately.

It's installed into a project by using:

```
npm link <myPackage>
```

It's great, but there's a problem if the `<myPackage>` have a require(path).

It'll use the real location of `<myPackage>` as __dirname, for example, instead of the expected location of the symlink, that should be local to the project, like a regular node_module.

The solution I found so far, for my particular case works fine:

```
module.exports = {
  loadImage: function (filename) {
    var img
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && ({}).toString.call(window) === '[object Window]') {
      try {
        img = require('../../src/images/' + filename)
      } catch (e) {
        // Development only
        img = require('./template/src/images/' + filename)
      }
    } else {
      img = '/assets/images/' + filename
    }
    return img
  }
}
```

But as you can imagine, this cause Warning messages in the Browser.

While I'm aware of the reason why of this problem, ideally, I'd like to suppress the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it won't be a very popular question, in that case, here's a nice option that won't cause any warning messages and that is quite specific to the NPM Package development stage.

The following modules.exports expose some code snippets you'd like to import into your application. You'll find the `loadImage` method, with a fallback for the require(path):

```
module.exports = {
  loadImage: function (filename) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && ({}).toString.call(window) === '[object Window]') {
      return (process.env.NPM_PACKAGE_DEV && require('./template/src/images/' + filename) ||
            require('./template/src/images/' + filename))
    } else {
      return '/assets/images/' + filename
    }
  },
  isBrowser: function () {
    return (typeof window !== 'undefined' && ({}).toString.call(window) === '[object Window]')
  }
}
```

What's good about this, is that you can set the NPM_PACKAGE_DEV by running the command, than initialize the node server (osx terminal syntax):

```
export NPM_PACKAGE_DEV=1 && node server.js
```

If the NPM_PACKAGE_DEV is omitted, the require() fallback to the end use path, that is relative to the project node_modules directory.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!